# Monitor JVM on tomcat service

Tags: java, jvm, monitoring, tomcat6

Hi I noticed that different tools for monitoring JVM require that the process will be java.exe in the taskbar. Its process id is supplied to them and then statistics regarding garbage collection and etc are returned. When running tomcat as a service, there is no a process named jave.exe but it is tomcat6.exe.
How can I get statistics regarding the JVM tomcat6 uses ?

Comment: It looks as though matt b answered your question, so you can mark it as answered to give him credit.

Answer (score 5):

[Enable JMX in Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html) and then connect via JConsole or JVisualVM. The name of the process is not relevant.